# Accesing a member directly by the class name

Tags: c#, class, oop, struct

Im trying to create a ufloat class/struct in c#. It's more of a challenge for me, but would help me control some values in code. After trying a couple of approaches, I finally have one that seems to work:

```
public struct ufloat
{
    public float Value
    {
        get{ return value; }
        set
        {
            if(value < 0)
            {
                this.value = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                this.value = Math.Abs(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, I want it to behave like a typical basic type:

```
ufloat n = 5;
n += 1;
```

After some thinking I tried to overload the '=' operator, but it is not possible. Now I am out of ideas. This is why I ask, how can you change this:

```
ufloat x; x.value = 1;
```

to this:

```
ufloat x = 0; x = 1;
```

?

(Sorry if I am losing something really easy, but I am a self-taught "programmer" and I am pretty new to c#. I learnt c++ at first, and going from lower to higher level isn't easy for me.)

Comment: You need a private variable with a different name than the property, otherwise the `this.value =` parts inside the `set { }` will call the `set` again and you get a stack overflow...

Comment: Could you clarify - was `n =+ 1` really what you meant (with a new value of 1) or did you mean `n += 1` (where you'd want the result to be 6)?

Comment: @Nyerguds thanks for pointing this out... looks like recursion is still haunting me.

Comment: @JonSkeet No, it was +=, I just didn't see that. Oops. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't overload the `=` operator, but you can overload the `+` operator, and then the `+=` operator (which I believe you meant instead of `=+`) will work in a reasonably obvious way. You'd also need to add an implicit conversion from `float` to your struct though.

I would strongly advise *not* making the struct mutable though - instead, let the `+` operator return a *new* value. That will make it behave like every other primitive type, and like most other structs. I'd also rename it to `USingle` to follow the normal .NET naming conventions (where `Single` is the CLR name for `float`). You can't add your own C# alias for a name like `float` is for `Single` though.

I suspect your type will want:

- A constructor accepting a `float`
- Conversions to and from `float` (note that normally implicit conversions shouldn't throw exceptions - you *may* want to ignore that, but I'm not sure...)
- Overloads for the arithmetic operators (`+`, `-`, `*` and `/`)
- Overrides of `ToString`, `Equals` and `GetHashCode`
- Implementation of `IComparable<USingle>` and `IEquatable<USingle>`

You should think about what you want to happen if you add two values which are "large positive floats" together - is the intention that your new type is able to support larger positive values than `float` can, or is it just "`float` but always non-negative"?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! But I just want to know one more thing. Why make the  type inmutable? Is it just a good practice?

Comment: @czajnikzrawy: For value types, yes, almost always. It makes them much easier to reason about. Personally I like immutability for classes in many cases, but almost *always* for value types.

Comment: no, I just need a positive float. Nothing more. Thanks for writing such an informative answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can not overload `=` operator but you may write implicit casts, for example this one is for casting an int:

```
public class ufloat
{
    public float value { get; }
    public ufloat(int val) {  value = Math.Abs(val); }
    public static implicit operator ufloat(int input) 
    {
         return new ufloat(input);
    }
}
```

Now if you assign an int value to it, it will implicitly be converted to ufloat:

```
ufloat x = -5;
```

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't think of that before. That's a pretty way to get over the = operator overload. Also, it makes sense - there are many types, a lot of them need separate attention.

Comment: While that will allow the conversion itself, it's not going to help with `+=`

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I know. I kinda put it in my question because I wanted to show the typical things you can do with a type. But thanks anyway, I'll totally need it too!